# How to add characters to the output of a permutation in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to make in Haskell a application that gives from a couple of characters all possibilities. That works with the permutation function. But now I want to add to the output of every word in the list a prefix and a suffix. Like:

**Input:**

```
combinations "prefix" "sufix" "randomletters"
```

**Output (something like this)**

```
["prefixrandomletters", "prefixrandomletters","prefixrandomletters","prefixrandomletters","suffixrandomletters","suffixrandomletters","suffixrandomletters","suffixrandomletters","suffixrandomletters",]
```

**Background of the application:**
Like scrabble. First the prefix is like 2 letters that the word can start with. Then 2 letters that the word can end with. Then the letters you have in your hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` a function that adds the prefix:

```
combinations pre suf letters = prefixed ++ suffixed
  where
    perms = permutations letters
    prefixed = map (\x -> pre ++ x) $ perms
    suffixed = ...
```

The way to solve this is to break the problem down, as you have started doing:

- create a function to give every permutation (`permutation`)
- create functions to add the prefix & suffix (`\x -> pre ++ x` etc)
- apply these functions to every permutation (`map`) to create two lists of words
- combine the two lists of words (`++`)

Comment: @user2502169, I just updated my answer. (I've left it to you to complete the implementation for suffixes. :) )